# UIImageView doesn't add to the UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Hi I have a UIScrollView that I add programatically and then in which I add a UIImageView as a subview, the problem is that the UIImageView isn't showing in the UIScrollView.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class InstagramBigCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
private let instagramImageThumb = UIImageView()

var urlString: String!

func initialize() {
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    instagramImageThumb.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
    scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.zoomWhenDoubleTap))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    self.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topAnchor).active = true
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.leadingAnchor).active = true
   // scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.trailingAnchor).active = true
  //  scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomAnchor).active = true
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)

    instagramImageThumb.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    scrollView.addSubview(instagramImageThumb)

    instagramImageThumb.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)

    print(instagramImageThumb.frame)
   //here we can see that the frame is set as well

 }

func zoomWhenDoubleTap(){
    let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size
    var rectToZoomTo = CGRect()

    let width = scrollViewSize.width
    let height = scrollViewSize.height
    let x:CGFloat = 0.0
    let y:CGFloat = 0.0
    rectToZoomTo = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    self.scrollView.zoomToRect(rectToZoomTo, animated: true)

    }
}

 extension InstagramBigCollectionViewCell: UIScrollViewDelegate {

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return instagramImageThumb
   }
}
```

Any idea why?

EDIT: the UIScrollView's bounds are set and the frame is there, but for some reason just the UIImageView doesn't appear on screen

EDIT2: Showing all code

The initialize gets called in cellForItemAt: in the UICollectionViewDataSouce

Comment: what do you mean ? I am initializing it at the top and add it to the view in the initialize function

Comment: Please show all relevant code.

Comment: this is all relevant code

Comment: ok now i show you all ... i tried both the commented option and the uncommented option ... the frame for the scrollview is set as I mentioned and displayed properly on screen, the frame for the UIImageView seems to be there but it is not shown .... as said above

Comment: @shallowThought how about now?

Comment: I got confused. I expected a ViewController as you wrote "its called in viewDidLoad()" in a comment you did deleted now. So I decided to go on working.

Comment: ok ... well I don't think it matters really what type of class is it or so, after all it does not load in a different way than the normal way if it is in a ViewController or a Cell ... but sure ... thanks

Comment: Where are you setting the frame of the scroll view?